# Should I comment on changes that I made to my answer or not?

Tags: support, edits, comments

Often after I have supplied an answer to the original question, I get feedback from the questioner, which either clarifies the original question or actually extends the original question. To take that into consideration, I edit my post and maybe change the initial answer or add another example to it.

After that I want to make sure, that the questioner *(or also the user that gave the last comments to my answer)* actually becomes aware of my change. So I tend to add another comment, just saying something like: *"please check my answer, I updated it with another example"* or *"thank you for your comment, I took your change into consideration"* and addressing it to the last commenter to make sure, the change will be noticed.

I somehow have the strange feeling, this cannot be the desired procedure...

To summarize:

1. I supply an answer to a question.
2. The questioner or another user comments on my answer.
3. I change my answer to reflect the comment.

Will the questioner/commenter always be automatically informed about my change? Or do have to write an *@username* comment to address him directly and spam the comments block?

Comment: If you @reply to someone who commented on your own answer it's not spamming anyone. It only notifies one person. That's fewer notifications than if everyone who commented gets updated when an answer changes.

Comment: on a second thought, that does make sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Users do not get a notification if an answer they have commented on is edited.

Comment: ok, so i do understand then that writing i comment to user, that answer is updated, is kind of spam, but the only solution to keep their attention... hmmm. maybe a feature request? if i comment any answer, i would not mind being informed on changes

Comment: Would favoriting the _question_ also alert you to edits to existing answers?

Comment: @ryanyuyu It would highlight the question as yellow from the view of all favorites until you viewed the question.

Comment: @Servy ah so it doesn't actually push any notifications of updates as a favorite?  It just passively lets you know (via highlight) in the favorites tab that stuff has happened?